# Why OData api called multiple times in power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI Desktop application that accesses one Data Source which is an OData feed. When refreshing the data in Power BI Desktop it takes much longer . After clicking on Refresh in the popup it shows "Evaluating" and "Loading 2 KB..." for a very long time. From logs of OData API,I can see that the OData feed is called twice and each request is taking same amount of time.

Why does Power BI desktop call the OData feed multiple times? Is there a way to reduce the number of calls?

Note:

1. I have gone through [Referenced Queries And Caching In Power BI And
   Power Query Blog](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/11/20/referenced-queries-and-caching-in-power-bi-and-power-query/) But in my case my not using any transformation.
   Just loading OData feed.
2. I have gone through [the post for same
   issue at Power BI community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/OData-refresh-called-multiple-times/m-p/344309#M154385) and try the suggested approach but
   still issue persists.

Comment: Check this out and see if it helps. https://youtu.be/3uKNNZqBIkg?t=330

Answer (score 1):

Case is similar to "why-is-power-bi-running-my-sql-query-twice"

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/07/05/why-is-power-bi-running-my-sql-query-twice/

Power BI wants to know the schema of the table before the query actually runs, so it asks Power Query to return the top 0 rows. Probably its also true for OData.

Using M function Table.View should help.

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/05/14/speed-up-data-refresh-performance-in-power-bi-desktop-using-table-view/